# An expectation inequality

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid random variables, and $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$, prove that $$\mathbb E[|X+Y|]\geq\mathbb E[|X-Y|]$$

Let $F(x)$ denote the distribution, after calculation, I need to prove 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x[1-F(x)-F(-x)]F(dx)\geq0$$
but I stuck with it. Any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take $G(x)=F(x)+F(-x)$, $F'(x) = f(x)$

$2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(1 - F(x) - F(-x)) f(x) dx = 2\int_0^{\infty} x (1 - G(x)) f(x) - 2\int_0^{\infty} x(1 - G(-x))f(-x)dx = 2\int_0^{\infty} x(1-G(x)) (f(x) - f(-x)) = 2\int_0^{\infty} x(1-G(x))G'(x) dx 
\\= \displaystyle -x(1- G(x))^2\Big|_0^{\infty} + \int_0^{\infty} (1 -G(x))^2 dx =\int_0^{\infty} (1 -G(x))^2 dx \ge 0$

It is easy to show that $x(1 - G(x))^2 \to 0$, when $x\to \infty$, using the fact the expectation is finte.

Comment: I think $F$ need to be absolutely continuous, then $F$ can have derivative a.s..

Comment: @Danielsen Actually you do not have to, this is just a more complicate way to do this, I used to know an easier method without using this.

Comment: Could you please write the details?

Comment: @Danielsen I cannot remember it now, that is why I said I used to. And if $f$ is Lesbegue integrable, then the above still works.

Comment: There should be a prettier way of proving the original inequality. Perhaps by some symmetry argument?