# $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|c_i+c_j|a_ia_j\geq\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|c_i-c_j|a_ia_j$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let $c_i\in\mathbb R$, $a_i\geq0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$, prove
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|c_i+c_j|a_ia_j\geq\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|c_i-c_j|a_ia_j$$
This inequality comes from [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284989/an-expectation-inequality), when $X$ is simple random variable.
Any help, thanks!