# Seeking a More Elegant Proof to an Expectation Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, alternative-proof, integral-inequality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. random variables, and $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$, prove that $$\mathbb E[|X+Y|]\geq\mathbb E[|X-Y|].$$

---

This question is a re-posting of [An expectation inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284989/an-expectation-inequality). I can prove this with integration. But there must be a more elegant proof via perhaps a symmetry argument. Can someone come up with such a one?

Comment: @Shalop: Good. Your variation of the problem does not require i.i.d..

Comment: True, although whenever $X, Y \geq 0$, then $X+Y \geq |X-Y|$.  The interesting part of this proposition is that you can "slide" the distributions left and right, as it were, and it remains true.  For that, you do need i.i.d. (or something akin to that).

Comment: Hans, you could submit your solution by integration in the linked thread (otherwise it will remain unanswered).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: The linked question already has the intermediate form of the integration needed for the proof of this current question, if not explicitly stated. That question does not ask to derive the integral, but that the integral is positive. If I write out the derivation of the integral, it does not seem to answer that linked question per se. Would you agree?

Comment: Hans: I believed you had an other proof with integration. Actually you were referring to the answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first observation is that $|x+y|\geqslant|x-y|$ if and only if $xy\geqslant 0$, so defining 
$$f(x,y):=|x+y|-|x-y|,$$
the positivity of $f$ is linked to that of $xy$. We would like to find a more tractable expression for $f$.

- Assume that $x\gt 0$ and $ y\gt 0$. Then $f(x,y)=x+y-|x-y|=2\min\{x,y\}
  =\min\{|x|,|y|\}$.
- Since $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$ we get $f(x,y)=2\min\{|x|,|y|\}$ if $xy\gt 0$.
- Assume that $x\gt 0$ and $y\lt 0$. Then $x-y\gt 0$, hence $|x-y|=x-y$
  $$f(x,y)=|x+y|+y-x=-(x-y-|x-(-y)|)=-2\min\{x,-y\}=-2\min\{|x|,|y| \}.$$
- By symmetry of $f$, we obtain this expression if $x\lt 0$ and $y\gt 0$.

To sum up: for each $(x,y)\in\mathbf R^2$, 
$$f(x,y)= 2\min\{|x|,|y|\}\left(\mathbf 1\{xy\gt 0\}-\mathbf 1\{xy\lt 0\}\right).$$
Now we compute the expectation: using the fact that the random variable are i.i.d., we have 
$$\mathbb E[\min\{|X|,|Y|\}\mathbf 1\{XY\gt 0\}]=\int_0^{+\infty}\mu\{X\gt t\}^2+ \mu\{-X\gt t\}^2\mathrm dt  \mbox{ and }   $$
$$\mathbb E[\min\{|X|,|Y|\}\mathbf 1\{XY\lt 0\}]=2\int_0^{+\infty}\mu\{X\gt t\}\cdot \mu\{-X\gt t\} \mathrm dt. $$
This follows from the equality
$$\mathbb E[Y]=\int_0^{+\infty}\mu\{Y\gt t\}\mathrm dt $$
and the fact that 
$$\mu\left(\{ \min\{|X|,|Y|\}\gt t \}\cap\{X\gt 0\}\cap\{Y\gt 0\}\right) 
=\mu\{X\gt t\}\mu\{Y\gt t\} ,$$
$$\mu\left(\{ \min\{|X|,|Y|\}\gt t \}\cap\{X\lt 0\}\cap\{Y\lt 0\}\right) 
=\mu\{-X\gt t\}\mu\{-Y\gt t\}\mbox{ and }   $$
$$\mu\left(\{ \min\{|X|,|Y|\}\gt t \}\cap\{X\lt 0\}\cap\{Y\gt 0\}\right) 
=\mu\{X\gt t\}\mu\{-Y\gt t\}.   $$
We thus infer that 
$$\mathbb E|X+Y|-\mathbb E|X-Y|=2
\int_0^{\infty}\left(\mu\{X\gt t\}-\mu\{-X\gt t\} \right)^2\mathrm dt. $$
This gives the wanted lower bound, and it shows that the equality is achieved if and only if $X$ is symmetric.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Another way to sum up: $f(x,y)=2\{\min(x^+,y^+)+\min(x^-,y^-)-\min(x^+,y^-)-\min(x^-,y^+)\}$.

Comment: Excellent expansion of $f(x,y)$! Could you please add some details of the derivation of the integration of $\mu$'s? I suppose there is a collection of terms in domain $XY<0$, and some integration by parts involved. In the integration by parts, the vanishing of the end terms needs to be justified by the finiteness of $\mathbb E[|X|]$. It will be more interesting you obtain this without integration by parts. If so, writing out the derivation is even more desirable.

Comment: @Hans I have added some details.

Comment: Thank you. $\mathbb E[Y]=\int_0^{+\infty}\mu\{Y\gt t\}\mathrm dt$ for positive $Y$ come from integration by parts from the definition of $\mathbb E$ and stands under the condition that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}(1-\mu(Y>t))t=0$. The last condition is satisfied as $\mathbb E[|Y|]<\infty$. Do you agree? Do you think it would be good to add that if you do?

Comment: Actually this is more Fubini's theorem than integration by parts (and the formula is also valid if $Y$ is not integrable, it give $+\infty$ on both sides).